# Making a custom angle symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, macros

I want to create a mathematical symbol as below.

[image]

This symbol should be exactly the same as the usual `\angle` command (with the `amsfonts` package) in terms of dimensions: it should not be wider or taller. It should have the same 'arc' as in `\measuredangle` (but **not** its dimensions, since this is taller). And of course, it should be filled with gray: `\color{gray}` (with the `xcolor` package). I want to be able to use it in an equation like `\(\filledangle ABC\)`, identical to how commands like `\angle` are used. How can I do this? I have a sense that I would perhaps need to define a macro perhaps using tikz; but I have no clue where to start.

I can draw the figure by itself quite easily. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=gray] (0,0) -- +(45:2) arc (45:0:2) -- (0,0);
    \draw (0,0)--(45:3) (0,0)--(0:3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces something similar to what I want, but I am not sure that this is the correct scale used in `\angle`, nor do I know how to get this into the form of a command in math mode or how to get it to scale correctly.

P.S. This symbol should scale properly and be of the correct relative size to the math beside it; e.g. if I type `\(x^{\filledangle ABC}\)` for whatever reason, the symbol should turn smaller accordingly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice problem to play with, but could you share what you have tried so far as an `MWE`. This will help us to have an head-start rather than starting from scratch!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope to have understood your question. By changing the coordinates you can adjust the angle as you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\newcommand{\comangle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw coordinate (a) at (0.3,0);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (.2,0.25);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) pic [draw=black,fill=gray!50,angle radius=.2cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\comangle{} your new symbol.

\end{document}
```

**VARIATION**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\newcommand{\comangle}{\kern.08em%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw coordinate (a) at (0.15,0);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (.14,0.25);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) pic [draw=black,fill=gray!50,angle radius=.11cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\kern.08em%
}
\begin{document}
$\angle A$

$\comangle A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems great, except for several issues. First, this by default takes an argument which is really inconvenient, but this is easily fixed so it is not a large problem. A bigger issue is that the spacing after `\comangle` is different from that after `\angle`, leading to inconsistency. Using `x^{\comangle}` also doesn't scale the symbol at all, and most appallingly neither does changing font size. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There were two spurious spaces in the solution. I fixed them for you by ending two lines with a `%` character. Hope you don't mind. ;-)

Comment: Another suggested improvement: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em,y=1em]` and multiply all coordinates by 3 (more or less). Then it will scale with font size. Possibly, one can argue that using `1ex` instead of `1em` is better. Or you can just use some other multiple of `em` or `ex` and leave the numbers inside alone. You choose. PS. If you want to use this in math mode, possibly some more work is needed, like wrapping the whole construct in `\mathop{}`.

Comment: It seems the most versatile approach.  Bravo!

Comment: To make it similar dimensions to `\angle`, you could try something like `\newcommand{\comangle}{\kern.08em%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw coordinate (a) at (0.15,0);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (.14,0.25);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) pic [draw=black,fill=gray!50,angle radius=.11cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\kern.08em
}`  Then, compare `$\angle A$

$\comangle A$`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think that's certainly worthy of a great answer. Would you mind typing it out in full for me? :)

Comment: @Teyyf Since it is based on Sebastiano's code, I think it should be incorporated into his answer.  He deserves the credit!  I just added a tweak.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Nice. (You don't need the `%` after `\kern.08em`: TeX syntax specifies an ⟨optional space⟩ at the end of a ⟨unit of measure⟩.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks.  I place them there out of habit, all the while knowing they are not needed also when line ends in a macro, when in math mode, etc.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you very much much for edit and implementation of my small code. You are great!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I've always tried to do my best. Obviously I didn't expect the user to ask `x^{\comangle}`. A possible solution that could be obtained with scalerel, of resize, etc.. A cordial greeting.

Comment: No complaints from me. 8-) Actually, I have no idea what happens to the em unit when in scriptmode. Does it reflect the textmode font? (I *could* try to find out, but have other pressures at the moment.)